# How can I pass a QEvent to an object owned by the receiver?

Tags: c++, qt, events, event-handling

How can an event received by a class through the [QObject::event()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#event) function be passed to one of its data members, which would then handle the event?

For example, if I have

```
class A
{
    B b;
    public:
        event(QEvent *);   
    //other members and functions
};
```

and

```
class B
{
    public:
        event(QEvent *);
    //other members
};
```

Suppose I send the event from another function, an event filter to an object of `A` using `postEvent()`, from what I understand, the `event()` function of `A` receives the event. Is there a way to pass on the event to a member of `A`, `B` instead, which will then handle the event?

Comment: In `A::event(QEvent *e)` just call `b.event(e)`?

Comment: @peppe I am new to Qt, I didn't know this was possible. Isn't event a function that listens for events, and acts on events that get added to the event queue of the object? Can we explicitly call it?

Comment: Sure, it's an "ordinary" C++ member function. If you want also to activate B's event filters etc. you may use `QCoreApplication::sendEvent`.

Comment: @peppe `QObject::event` is meant to be called by Qt. Invoking it directly breaks the object's contract for all of its users. If you're the only user, perhaps you can deal with that, but such brokenness is at odds with maintainability and there's no reason to break it in the first place :)

Comment: I'm more curious about why the delegation is needed in OP's design, but that requires more information.

Comment: @peppe I have a common event filter, that filters events and posts it to the appropriate object. Within my object, (A), I have an object (B) which is dedicated to handling the events received by A (in particular, keypress events) and set variables and call functions as appropriate based on it.
Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Can't B be A's event filter?

Comment: @peppe Thank you very much for that. I hadn't understood filters properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `QCoreApplication::sendEvent`:

```
class B : public QObject
{
public:
  bool event(QEvent *);
};

class A : public QObject
{
  // Correct
  B b{this};
  // Wrong
  B bad;
public:
  bool event(QEvent * ev) override {
    if (ev->type() == my_event_type) {
      // Correct
      return QCoreApplication::sendEvent(&b, ev);
      // Wrong
      return b.event(&ev);
    }
    return QObject::event(ev);
  }
};
```

In C++98, without uniform initialization, you'd have to use initializer lists instead:

```
class A : public QObject
{
  B b;
public:
  A(QObject * parent = 0) : QObject(this), b(this) {}
  bool event(QEvent * ev) { /*...*/ };
};
```

#### Pitfalls to Avoid

1. The parentage of `B` is critical in ensuring that it lives in the same thread as `A`. Users of `A` are free to move it to any thread - that's the contract of `QObject` (breaking it is a bad idea). When they do, `sendEvent` turns into undefined behavior unless `B` is in the same thread. The canonical way to ensure that related objects follow thread changes it to parent them to the object they should track.
2. Don't invoke `QObject::event()` directly: it's only meant to be invoked by Qt. Calling it directly would bypass the event filters and cause `B` not to behave like a `QObject`. Part of `QObject`s contract is that event filters (at various levels) can modify its functionality. Invoking `event()` directly would break [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) for *all of `B`'s users!* : they'd be using a `QObject`, but it'd not act like a `QObject` would anymore.

Comment: Thank you! I could not clearly understand point 1. If `B` is a member of `A`, what is the meaning of both being in different threads? Moreover, could you explain why you have used `B b{this};`? Thank you.

Comment: A `QObject` has a thread affinity. Each object's thread affinity is separate, unless the objects are related. Just because the object `B` is held in a place that physically is a part of `A`, it doesn't mean that it knows anything about `A`: by default, it's completely decoupled from `A` and only `A` knows that they are related - not `b`. By making `b` a child of `A`, you let the object know its parent and thus have it follow the thread of `A`.

Comment: Without making `b` a child of `A`, you could do `A a; a.moveToThread(someThread)` and now you broke `b`!

Comment: The `B b{this}` is uniform initialization: it constructs an instance of `B` via the `B::B(QObject*)` constructor, where `this` is the pointer to the instance of `A` where `b` lives.

Comment: Thank you. In my case, I have a custom defined constructor for b in place, so I suppose that will override the default constructor of QObject. What should I do in this case? Should I call `setParent()` in my constructor?

Comment: Your constructor should take the parent as the last argument and forward it to the base class's constructor: `explicit B::B(int arg1, int arg2, bool arg3, QObject * parent = nullptr) : QObject{parent}, m_val1{arg1} /*...*/ { /*...*/ }`